# Unable to start Jfrog Artifactory: Fresh Install

Tags: artifactory

After the fresh install of JFrog Artifactory server I am not able to start up the application. I am using a percona 5.6 mysql db server.

---

```
artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: resources) since Mon 2018-01-22 04:22:34 EST; 2s ago
  Process: 8618 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 22 04:22:34 xxx-xxxx-xxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine.
Jan 22 04:22:34 xxx-xxxx-xxxx systemd[1]: Unit artifactory.service entered failed state.
Jan 22 04:22:34 xxx-xxxx-xxxx systemd[1]: artifactory.service failed.
```

---

When I checked artifactory.bootstrap.log I am getting following error.

```
2018-01-22 04:07:43 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO ] master.key file currently missing - waiting for Access to create it. Reattempting to check master.key file existence in 1 second.
```

If you need any more logs to diagnose please let me know.

Regards,

Comment: looks like the Access service did not start successfully, can you check you catalina logs (in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/catalina/ ) ? Might be Access which cannot connect to your mysql DB server

Comment: Had to give up on this approach and went with a docker install. Thank you for the advice. Will try this one more time later.

Comment: Had to give up on this approach and went with a docker install, Will try this one more time later.

Comment: How long did you let the process run? I was impatient with my first run. When Artifactory started spewing errors - mostly that "master.key file currently missing" I stopped it and tried again. Turns out the error message is expected. I unpacked the zip again to replace any corrupted config/derby files and reran. After about a minute the errors stopped, Access was up and the landing page worked.

Comment: @jroquelaure, what is the Access service? How can I verify that it is running, which version it is, and whether that version matches with what Artifactory expects?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Running under Ubuntu 16.04 and the deb installation package for 5.10.1.

It looks like the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME` points to `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory`, with the binaries in `/opt/jfrog/artifactory`. Changing `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME` to point to `/opt/jfrog/artifactory` allows it to start, but puts all the data there as well (access, backup, data, logs and support directories). This is fine for me as we only have a demo licence and we're just doing some testing, but less than ideal if you want to keep your data under `/var`.

I did try leaving `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME` alone and creating links to the other directories but that didn't seem to work. I haven't bothered investigating that though, since I now have a test system that looks like it works.

Answer (score 1):

i got similar issue  and fixed it by correcting owner / group permissions on /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/access/etc path.

i was creating the below directories using ansible playbook before running artifactory docker image.

/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/access/etc

/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/backup
  /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data
  /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc
  /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs

Answer (score 1):

I had this error recently with version 6.7.3 using java 8 on Solaris 11. 
First I unzipped the file, checked all my file permissions, they were good.
Then, I set my ARTIFACTORY_HOME and JAVA_HOME in the artifactory.default file

Next, I ran the following 
openssl rand -hex 16 > /m1/artifactory-oss-6.7.3/etc/security/master.key

and started Artifactory.

I found the openssl command to manually create  the master.key here: 
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15699

Comment: Please note that this only works if it's really the first time Artifactory starts with an empty database. If the database already contains the key from a previous installation, then that key must be used and a newly generated key would result in yet another error: "Master key checksum mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Master+Key+Encryption

go to **Security** >> **Security Configuration**  >> **Encript** button

that will create the *artifactory.key* file, duplicate it and rename the copy to *master.key*

**Edit 1**

found out in version 5 you need the ***JAVA_HOME*** set, in version 4 doesn't matter,

Comment: how can I "go to Security >> Security Configuration >> Encript button" if Artifactory won't even start up?

Comment: @SethTisue sorry i forget to mention if u where upgrading, i got the same situation migrating from 4 to 5

Answer (score 0):

You will get these kind of messages in the log if the DB-connection fails also.
There was error messages about the DB-connection earlier but they where hidden by secondary failures.

The `master.key` is created after the DB is initialized.